# Button To Generate Multiple Database Entries MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

In my MVC 3 project (for a company that give lessons), I have about 100 clients in a database and the amount they pay per month is constant - it's either R640 or R460, depending on whether they're enrolled for a group or a private lesson. What I want to do is, have one button that when clicked, will generate database entries for invoices for each client for the current month - so will generate 100 invoices. Would this be difficult to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.
you would have your button link to a controller action maybe called GenerateInvoices?
Then loop through each client and do the checks and the database writings you need done.

Just write the code and have the buttons action be the controller action.